# Pandas iterate over rows and build new frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question, currently I have for example the following dataframe (this is just an excerpt, in reality it would be a lot bigger (about a few million rows).

```
            topic     keyword                                                             
    0    String A    String A
    1    String A    String B
    3    String B    String A
    4    String B    String B
    5    String B    String D
    6    String C    String D
...
```

Now I kind of want to keep the first co-occurence sort of, if String B is already "taken" in the "keyword" column, it cannot be in the topic column anymore. IF it's the first time though, keep it.

```
            topic     keyword                                                             
    0    String A    String A
    1    String A    String B
    3    String B    String A -> Topic is already used in keyword, so delete it
    4    String B    String B -> Topic is already used in keyword, so delete it
    5    String B    String D -> Topic is already used in keyword, so delete it
    6    String C    String D
...
```

In the end I'd like the following result.

```
            topic     keyword                                                             
    0    String A    String A
    1    String A    String B
    2    String C    String D
...
```

How can I achieve this in the fastest fashion?

Comment: Can't you just use ```drop_duplicates``` on your keyword column and keep the first occurence? Something like ```df.drop_duplicates(subset='keyword',keep = 'first')``` ?

Comment: This does not work, they want to compare the keywords with the topic. `drop_duplicates` compares keywords to itself.

Comment: @AliHejazizo What is the comparison to the topic column here? It's not used right!

Comment: I don'T understand the question: "what is the comparison?" - Unfortunately drop_duplicates is not suitable

Comment: I think it will help if you elaborate on what exactly you are looking for? ```Topic is already used in keyword``` is not really clear

Comment: The strings in "topic" and "keyword" are the same in case of "String A" for example, so when "topic" is "String B", but "String B" was already a keyword in topic "String A", then String B cannot be a topic itself anymore and the rows containing it as a topic are irrelevant and can be deleted or ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can try remove duplicated with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = (df[['topic','keyword']].stack()
                            .drop_duplicates()
                            .unstack()['topic']
                            .reindex(df.index)
                            .ffill())

df = df[df['topic'].eq(s)]
print (df)
      topic   keyword
0  String A  String A
1  String A  String B
5  String C  String D
```

Comment: very nice approach i think

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a for loop to create a new dataframe:

```
new_rows = []
keywords = set()
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['topic'] in keywords:
        continue
    keywords.add(row['keyword'])
    new_rows.append(row)

# this new df is what you want
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
```

Comment: definitely not the fastest approach :) it will take quite some time for a few million rows - I am not the downvoter, even though I am the one that left the comment.

Comment: Wasn't the downvoter either, thank you for this approach, I'll check it out

Comment: No worries. I just suggested this approach. Didn't mean that this is the best one. You probably can achieve the same results with some query on the dataframe.